# Parse a double string does not consider the current culture

Tags: javascript, c#

On javascript **client side** I send a **decimal** value:

```
"Latitude": 80.435435344
```

On **server side** I recieve a **string**:

```
"80,435435344"
```

Then I try to parse the **string**:

```
valueResult.AttemptedValue = "80,435435344";
NumberFormatInfo dbNumberFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
actualValue = double.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, dbNumberFormat);
```

My culture is "de-DE" that means its

`NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` has  a "," set

but when the **string** is parsed into a **double** its representation is:

```
80.435435344
```

Why is my comma gone?

Comment: The client can send to the server only strings, so my doubt is that you are actually sending 80,43... from the client and the server receives it as such. Is the value retrieved from FormCollection or something similar? It will also be helpful to show was how the value is used on client side, as your values sent on the wire should be culture independent.

Comment: Indeed - basically it's very unclear how/where you're seeing what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that in debugger because culture of Visual Studio is different of culture in your application, so there are no matters when you see dot instead comma in debugger, because application processes it in right way

Also when you stringify your double, you should specify format provider, which use commas instead of dots

```
double a = 80.435435344;
string aString = a.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
//or
string aString = a.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE").NumberFormat);
// Both solutions return 80,435435344
```

and you will get your comma back.

Comment: @Pascal then try to specify format provider, like in my answer

Comment: Hm... have you read my code? I am already using the NumberFormatInfo like you do and moreover I need to get a double as return value not string ;-)

Comment: Where do you see wrong separator? In debugger, in javascript or somewhere else?

Comment: While debugging the parsed value is => 80.435435344

Comment: It's so, because culture of Visual Studio is different of culture in your application, so there are no matters when you see dot instead comma in debugger, because application processes it in right way :-)

Comment: That means when I write a console app outputting that parsed double I would also see the string without a comma because I have a english Operation System? That means you can never be sure about the correct output because you still have another layer of UI between you and the conversion.

Comment: So how can I assert the result. Even a unit test will use the visual studio thread culture settings.

Comment: Try to use equality comparer explicitly `IEqualityComparer<double> comparer = EqualityComparer<double>.Default;
            comparer.Equals(a, b);`